# CSS background-image not working - not showing

Tags: background-image, gradient

my CSS:

```
background-image: url(/images/framework/arrow-down-small.png) no-repeat center; /* fallback */
                background-image: url(/images/framework/arrow-down-small.png) no-repeat center, -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#eee), to(#ccc)); /* Saf4+, Chrome */
                background-image: url(/images/framework/arrow-down-small.png) no-repeat center, -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eee, #ccc); /* Chrome 10+, Saf5.1+ */
                background-image: url(/images/framework/arrow-down-small.png) no-repeat center,    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eee, #ccc); /* FF3.6+ */
                background-image: url(/images/framework/arrow-down-small.png) no-repeat center,     -ms-linear-gradient(top, #eee, #ccc); /* IE10 */
                background-image: url(/images/framework/arrow-down-small.png) no-repeat center,      -o-linear-gradient(top, #eee, #ccc); /* Opera 11.10+ */
                background-image: url(/images/framework/arrow-down-small.png) no-repeat center,         linear-gradient(top, #eee, #ccc); /* W3C */
```

All I want is a background-image and a gradient at the same time. The HTML element is:

```
<input type="button" class="mybutton" />
```

But

- the background-image doesn't show at all
- the gradient isn't there

The absolute path is right because if I try a simple background:url(...) without gradient the image is there.

What's wrong?

Thanks
Bernhard

Answer (score 0):

With `no-repeat` you should skip the `-image`, try only with `background:`", such as :

```
background-image: url('image.png') no-repeat; /* Doesn't work */
background-image: url('image.png'); /* Works */
```

When you say you use only `background:` I think it does work because you aren't using `background-image`

And maybe you should try :

```
<input type = "image" class = "mybutton"/>
```

Hope that helps !

EDIT : Quotes are not mandatory

```
background-image: url(image.png);
background-image: url("image.png");
background-image: url('image.png');
```

Is the same thing

Comment: Yeah, thanks, de no-repeat and positioning was the point.
I always thought there is no need for quotes in the url because it always worked and I saw both versions out there?

Comment: You are right, I've modified my answer. Quotes are not mandatory